# Pandas groupby and remove row if group have number > than threshold

Tags: python, pandas

```
Group Col2 Col3
Grp1 1
Grp1 1
Grp1 1
Grp1 2
Grp1 3
Grp1 3
Grp2 1
Grp2 1
Grp2 1
Grp3 1
Grp3 2
Grp3 3
Grp4 1
```

And I would like to groupby groups and remove all groups from the data frame where the number in Col2 exceed 2 
Here I should get :

```
Group Col2
Grp2 1
Grp2 1
Grp2 1
Grp4 1
```

does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted the right to distribute your content under the CC By-SA license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use functions for compare like `eq` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and test if all values match by [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Col2'].eq(1).groupby(df['Group']).transform('all')]
print (df1)
   Group  Col2  Col3
6   Grp2     1   NaN
7   Grp2     1   NaN
8   Grp2     1   NaN
12  Grp4     1   NaN
```

Or get all groups where is at least one non match value with `ne` and filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['Group'].isin(df.loc[df['Col2'].ne(1), 'Group'])]
print (df)
   Group  Col2  Col3
6   Grp2     1   NaN
7   Grp2     1   NaN
8   Grp2     1   NaN
12  Grp4     1   NaN
```

If want compare for less like 2 values:

```
#get groups less like 2
df1 = df[df['Col2'].lt(2).groupby(df['Group']).transform('all')]
#remove groups greater of equal like 2
df1 = df[~df['Group'].isin(df.loc[df['Col2'].ge(2), 'Group'])]
```

---

List of all functions for compare:

- [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) - `<`
- [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) - `>`
- [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) - `<=`
- [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) - `>=`
- [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) - `!=`
- [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) - `==`

Comment: Thank you but how can I replace eq(1) to less(10) for instance ?

Comment: @Grendel - Then use `lt` for less.

Comment: @Grendel - Added functions to answer.

Comment: and what if I want something between 2 values for instance >= 2 or <= 10 [2:10] @jezrael

Comment: @Grendel - Then use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) like `df['Col2'].between(2, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

```
not_list = df[df['Col2'] == 2]['Group']
result = df[~df['Group'].isin(not_list)]
```